# What is the Lebesgue integral of $1/x$ on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I've seen this question asked a couple times here but the answers use materials I haven't learned yet. I think I should be able to solve this by finding $f_n(x)$ that converges to $f(x)$, but I don't really know any further than that. Any suggestions would be helpful. I should be able to solve this without invoking the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Answer accepted for [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801721/why-is-frac1x-not-lebesgue-integrable-on-0-1) question will also provide a simple solution

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=1/x$ is not $L^1([0,1])$. Consider the Riemman integral of $g_{\epsilon}:=f1_{[\epsilon,1]}$ on $[0,1]$, which gives
$$
\int_{\epsilon}^1f(x)\ dx=\log x\big|_\epsilon^1=-\log\epsilon
$$
Now let $\epsilon\to0+$.

Comment: if a function is not in L1 does that mean it's not Lebesgue integrable? The section on L1 in my textbook is poorly written.

Comment: $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ if and only if $\int_{[0,1]}|f|<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It's infinite; you can do that with Riemann sums, dividing the interval into $n$ equal subintervals. The integral on the interval $[\frac{m}{n}, \frac{m+1}{n}]$ is between $\frac{1}{n} \times \frac{n}{m+1}$ and $\frac{1}{n} \times \frac{n}{m}$ (i.e. "width of subinterval" times "min/max value on the subinterval"); i.e. between $\frac{1}{m+1}$ and $\frac{1}{m}$, and in particular at least $\frac{1}{m+1}$. So the total Riemann sum is at least $\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{m+1}$ for every $n$.

Comment: Can using Riemann sums be used to prove that a function is not Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: I showed that the Riemann integral is infinite, and hence the Lebesgue integral is infinite. (But yes, the sequence of unions of step functions I used, from which I derived the Riemann sums, together let us use the monotone convergence theorem.)